# Bitwise & over 32 bits

Tags: c, bitwise-and, c17

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long a = 9223372036854775808; // a = 2^63
    a = a & ~1;
    printf("%llu\n", a);
    printf("%d, %lld", INT_MAX, LLONG_MAX);
}
```

**Output**

```
9223372036854775808
2147483647, 9223372036854775807
```

This is the semantic of the `~` in C17(with my bold), 6.5.3.3.4.

> The result of the ~ operator is the bitwise complement of its (promoted) operand (that is, each bit in
> the result is set if and only if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set). **The integer
> promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.** If the promoted
> type is an unsigned type, the expression ~E is equivalent to the maximum value representable in
> that type minus E.

This is the semantic of the unary `&` in C17, 6.5.10.3.

> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.

`a` is equal to `9223372036854775808` which is equal to `8000 0000 0000 0000(16)`.

An integer constant `1` without any suffix is the same as `(int)1`. Therefore `~1` == `~(int)1` == `FFFF FFFE(16)`(integer promotion doesn't happen by `~`).

The type of `FFFF FFFE(16)` is converted to `unsigned long long` at
`a = 8000 0000 0000 0000(16) & FFFF FFFE(16)` by the usual arithmetic conversion. Therefore
`a = 8000 0000 0000 0000(16) & FFFF FFFE(16)` ==
`a = 8000 0000 0000 0000(16) & 0000 0000 FFFF FFFE(16)`

Finally,
`a = a & ~1` ==
`a = 8000 0000 0000 0000(16) & FFFF FFFE(16)` ==
`a = 8000 0000 0000 0000(16) & 0000 0000 FFFF FFFE(16)` ==
`a = 0000 0000 0000 0000(16)`

But the output says as if
`a = a & ~1` ==
`a = 8000 0000 0000 0000(16) & FFFF FFFE(16)` ==
`a = 8000 0000 0000 0000(16) & FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFE(16)` ==
`a = 8000 0000 0000 0000(16)`

My question is how the output is shown?

Comment: You might want to use `uint64_t` instead of `unsigned long long int` not only because it's less typing, but because it makes it clear what it is.

Comment: Hint: use `%x` rather than `%d` and use hexadecimal constants here (e.g. `0x8000`), it makes everything much simpler. I have no idea what `9223372036854775808` is but `0x8000000000000000` is clear

Comment: For your code I get `main.c:6:28: warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned`, which I can avoid by using `9223372036854775808ull`.

Comment: Try `printf("%x, %llx", INT_MAX, ULLONG_MAX);`. Note the `U...` (the `x` is not so important).

Comment: When `0xFFFF FFFE` is promoted from 32 bits to 64, the value is `0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFE`. In other words, it's sign extended to 64 bits, and then converted to unsigned. Converting to unsigned does nothing, but sign extension sets all of the upper bits. Of course, you can avoid the whole issue by using `~1ULL` in place of `~1`.

Comment: @user3386109 But in C17 6.3.1.3 1, "... , if the value
can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged". The value `0xFFFF FFFE` can be represented by the `unsigned long long`. So It should be converted to `0x 0000 0000 FFFF FFFE`. Can you give me that part of documentation?

Comment: @opol You see hex digits. The **compiler** just sees a number, and that number is negative. So the conversion from 32 bits to 64 bits must maintain that negative value. Assuming the implementation uses 2's complement, that negative value is maintained by copying the sign bit into the upper 32 bits of the 64 bit value. This isn't crystal clear in the spec because the spec doesn't mandate 2's complement. It still allows 1's complement and signed-magnitude representations of integer values.

Comment: @user3386109 I overlooked that `0xFFFF FFFE` is negative in 2's complement system. This value is converted to `-2 + (2^64-1) + 1` and it is the same as `0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFE`. Thank you.

Comment: "Therefore ~1 == ~(int)1 == FFFF FFFE(16)" is the beginning of the mistake. `~(int)1` may have the bit pattern FFFF FFFE(16), but its value did not change: still -2(16).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~1` in the twos complement system (all modern system - including your PC use it) is `-2`.

The binary representation of -2 in 4-byte long integer is `0xfffffffe`.

When you promote it to `long long integer` the value `-2` is preserved but the binary representation changes: `0xffffffffffffffffe`. This value is binary `AND`-ed with your variable `a` - so its value remains unchanged.

if you want to prevent this behaviour you need to tell the compiler what size data you want to use:

```
    a = a & ~(unsigned)1;
```

and it will behave as you expect

https://godbolt.org/z/G6757W

Comment: "When you promote it to long long integer" --> Why discuss `long long` as `-2` is converted to `unsigned long long` as part of `a & ~1`?

Comment: Indeed. There is no `long long` anywhere and no conversion to `long long` takes place. I don't understand this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the normal signed integer types such as `int` have a 2's complement representation in the following answer, otherwise the numeric value of `~1` would be something other than -2.

The integer constant `1` has type `int`. The expression `~1` will have the value -2 and type `int`.  Therefore, `a = a & ~1;` is equivalent to `a = a & -2;`.

Since `a` has type `unsigned long long` and `~1` has type `int`, then by the usual arithmetic conversions, the expression `~1` (numeric value -2) is converted to a value of type `unsigned long long` by mathematically adding (with infinite width) one more than `ULLONG_MAX` to the numeric value.  Therefore `a = a & ~1;` is equivalent to `a = a & -2;` which is equivalent to `a = a & (ULLONG_MAX - 1);`

Since `a` has the value `0x8000000000000000ull` (equivalent to `9223372036854775808ull`) and the least significant 64 bits of `ULLONG_MAX` have the value `0xffffffffffffffffull`, then the least significant 64 bits of `(ULLONG_MAX - 1)` have the value `0xfffffffffffffffeull`. Since `0x8000000000000000ull & 0xfffffffffffffffeull` is equal to `0x8000000000000000ull` and any bits beyond the first 64 bits of `a` are all zero, the value of `a` will be unchanged by the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to get what actually is the question.
So I was too late to beat P__J to the actually enlightening technical answer.

So I change my answer to a visualisation of the other answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long a = 9223372036854775808ull; // a = 2^63
    printf("%llx\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", ~1);
    printf("%x\n", (unsigned) ~1);
    printf("%llx\n", (unsigned long long )~1);
    a = a & ~1;
    printf("%llx\n", a);
    printf("%x, %llx, %llx", INT_MAX, LLONG_MAX, ULLONG_MAX);
}
```

Which gets you an output of

```
8000000000000000
-2
fffffffe
fffffffffffffffe
8000000000000000
7fffffff, 7fffffffffffffff, ffffffffffffffff
```

It does not have any implausibilities in my opinion.

I used some proposals from the comments, especially by Jabberwocky.

Comment: You and other people give me some developmental suggestion. I tried that all. But a difference is only the code becomes easy to read. Values and result are the same as before. I want to know why the result is `0x8000000000000000`. I expected `0` and the reason is in my question. I'm sorry my question is not clear.

Comment: @opol it is because `-2` is converted to 8 bytes integer - as in my answer\

Comment: Now, too late, I got the question and have found the answer. I take second place in visualising the accepted answer.

Comment: `printf("%llx\n", ~1);` is simply undefined behavior and possibly gives an out of bounds access.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks. Tricky little nasal demons. Hope I got it right now. And took the opportunity for another interesting step.

Answer (score 1):

"Therefore ~1 == ~(int)1 == FFFF FFFE(16)" is the beginning of the mistake.

`~(int)1` may have the *bit pattern* FFFF FFFE(16), but its *value* does not change: still -2(10) or -2(16).  It does not have the value of 4,294,967,294(10) or FFFF,FFFE(16).

When -2(16) is converted to `unsigned long long`, `ULLONG_MAX + 1`<sup>*</sup> is added to become 18,446,744,073,709,551,614(10) or FFFF,FFFF,FFFF,FFFE(16).

```
  8000 0000 0000 0000(16)
& FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFE(16)
= 8000 0000 0000 0000(16)
```

---

<sup>*</sup> When `unsigned long long` is 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

- Indeed no integer promotion takes place for the ~ operand since it is already `int`.
- `a & ~1;` is equivalent to `a & -2` (given 2's complement).
- The operand `a` is of type `unsigned long long`, the operand `-2` is of type `int`.
- Promotion happens according to the usual arithmetic conversions (C17 6.3.1.8):

  > Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
  > equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
  > signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
  > integer type.
- Which means that the rule regarding signed to unsigned conversion applies (C17 6.3.1.3):

  > Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
  > subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
  > until the value is in the range of the new type.
- The above refers to the pure mathematical calculation without caring about types. The maximum value `ULLONG_MAX` is 2^64 - 1. Add "one more" according to the above rule:

  -2 + 2^64 - 1 + 1 = 18446744073709551614 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE
- Now as it happens, this is the very same value as `-2` would get when sign extended to `signed long long` on 2's complement, but no such conversion to a larger signed type actually takes place anywhere.
- `0x8000000000000000 & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE` gives `0x8000000000000000`.